# iOS project with cocoa pods lost files if copy on new location

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I have developed an application using Cocoa Pods. When I copy the code to new location and change its name then I close the project and reopened it. It removes all the files from project as shown image:

[image]

Could anyone tell how can i solve the issue?

Comment: Sounds like your doing a few things wrong, could you expand on change name? Did update your pod file for the new target name etc. Have you ran pod install in the new location? If your opening the workspace, that's not going work because you changed the projects name. I suspect you want to rename from Xcode itself.

Comment: Yes, I am renaming the project from Xcode and I didn't update/install the pods again. should I reinstall the pods after renaming?

Comment: yes but you'll need to update your podfile for new scheme name first.

Comment: It will be done if i run the command "pod update"?

Comment: It will rebuild the pods and workspace but if you've changed the scheme name you need update your podfile , `target :MYNewName do`